# Rewriterule using apache htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What is the difference on

RewriteRule .* protecao_dos.php [NE,L]

and

RewriteRule ^$ protecao_dos.php [NE,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one:

```
 RewriteRule .* protecao_dos.php [NE,L]
```

Will catch a path with anything including empty resource path like `http://foo.com/` or `http://foo.com/arbitrary/long/path`.

The second one:

```
  RewriteRule ^$ protecao_dos.php [NE,L]
```

Will catch an empty path only like `http://foo.com/`